# Error handling external file: 'Inserting value to batch for column type DATE failed. Invalid argument provided.'

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, parquet, azure-synapse

I am reading parquet file and I found the two columns that cause this problem:

```
SELECT
TOP 100 
POST_SEARCH_DATE,
SEARCH_DATE 

FROM
OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'https://test/refined-parquet/data/v1.0/loaddt=2022-01-01/**',
    FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    
) AS [result]
```

These columns contain values that are undefined and I have tried the following to get rid of the error, yet it persists.

```
SELECT
TOP 100 
POST_SEARCH_DATE,
SEARCH_DATE

FROM
OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'https://test/refined-parquet/data/v1.0/loaddt=2022-01-01/**',
    FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    
) AS [result]
WHERE cast(POST_SEARCH_DEPARTURE_DATE as varchar(100))!= 'undefined'
and cast (SEARCH_DEPARTURE_DATE as varchar(100)) != 'undefined'
```

The code from above will throw the same:

> Error handling external file: 'Inserting value to batch for column type DATE failed. Invalid argument provided.'.

I also tried the following for one column:

```
SELECT
TOP 100 
POST_SEARCH_DATE,
SEARCH_DATE

FROM
OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'https://test/refined-parquet/data/v1.0/loaddt=2022-01-01/**',
    FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    
) with (POST_SEARCH_DATEVARCHAR(60)) AS [result]
```

But this throws the following:

> Error handling external file: 'Converting value to batch for column POST_SEARCH_DEPARTURE_DATE failed. Invalid argument provided.'

As instructed, no rows cannot be removed from this raw file and I am unsure how to solve this problem. Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the with clause and define the data type that you expect to receive when you perform the open row set ( see below ):

```
SELECT
  TOP 100 
  POST_SEARCH_DATE,
  SEARCH_DATE

FROM
   OPENROWSET(
      BULK 'https://test/refined-parquet/data/v1.0/loaddt=2021-01-01/**',
      FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
     WITH (
        [SEARCH_DEPARTURE_DATE] VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 3,
        [POST_SEARCH_DEPARTURE_DATE] VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 2
) AS [result]
```